# Mono - missing Socket.Bind and other methods

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin, gtk#

I need to rewrite my Visual Studio project in Xamarin Studio(Gtk#), but I havent some methods in Xamarin like:
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind, Thread.SetApartmentState. 
And I think this isn't full list.
How to use my Visual Studio methods in Xamarin or quick rewrite project?
Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio.  This is a .NET --> Mono issue.  Try to ask a more specific question, like "How to Bind a socket in Mono".  It also helps if you specify the platform you're targeting (presumably OS X) and what version of Mono you are running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously Mono supports both `Socket.Bind` and `Thread.SetApartmentState`,

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/Thread.cs

So you need to review which project type you use in Xamarin Studio, and what kind of references you use.

Comment: When I change target framework on .NET 3.5 I can use Bind method, but when I set .NET 4.0 I can't use Bind. Still can't use SetApartmentState on any framework version

Comment: That gives further hints on the problem. How did you get Mono and Xamarin Studio installed on this machine? Is this machine running Windows or OS X?

Comment: 1. I downloaded Xamarin studio from http://monodevelop.com/Download; 

2. Windows 7

Comment: Have you downloaded Mono 3.2 from http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html? Have you configured Xamarin Studio to use this Mono runtime as default?

Comment: I downloaded and installed mono, but how to configure Xamarin to use this Mono runtime?

Comment: Tools | Options -> Projects -> .NET Runtimes. Instead of using Microsoft .NET, switch to Mono and Set as Default.

Comment: I set Mono runtime as default, but after restart Xamarin still have 
notice "Xamarin Studio is currently running on Microsoft .NET".
Also have "Error: Error building target GetReferenceAssemblyPaths: UNC paths should be of the form \\server\share. (Project)" and haven't code hints.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue. Generally speaking, you should use MonoDevelop + Mono on Linux, or Xamarin Studio + Mono on OS X. Xamarin Studio + Mono on Windows is more troublesome, and it is not easy to know how to fix such issues.

Comment: I created a new project and now everything works fine.